# Has Anti-beta decay been observed?

Tags: resource-recommendations, antimatter, neutrinos, neutrons, weak-interaction

I am looking for references or resources regarding the transition of an anti-neutron through weak decay, into an anti-proton, positron, and electron-neutrino.

Have such studies been conducted or observations been made?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antineutron . observing antineutrons is very hard , so no decays to be seen let alone measured to the accuracy you want.

Comment: If you have not already done so, you might want to look at the answers to this closely related question: "[What is the measured decay rate of antineutrons? / What is the measured mean lifetime of antineutrons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/441056/145491)"

Comment: Measuring the anti-neutron lifetime is hard because it is so long, but experiments have measured and compared the lifetimes of much shorter-lived strange baryons and anti-baryons. The Particle Data Group's [Particle Listings](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2023/listings/contents_listings.html) are a good place to start. For example, the $\Lambda$ and $\bar{\Lambda}$ lifetimes differ by not more than about 1%, and the $\Sigma^+$ and $\overline{\Sigma^+}$ differ by not more than about 0.1%.