# Does antimatter have the same half-life as ordinary matter?

Tags: nuclear-physics, antimatter, isotopes, half-life

Antimatter is just ordinary matter but with opposite electric charge.
Scientists have created only a handful of antihelium-4 in the LHC.
I am wondering if the half-life of, say, antiRadium-226 is around 1600 years as it is for Radium-226. Have we measured the half-lives of any antimatter atoms?

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing some English and spelling mistakes. Please check that I have retained the original intent of your question.

Comment: As mentioned here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/441056/123208 we haven't yet measured the mean lifetime of the free antineutron. And it's not easy to precisely measure the mean lifetime of the normal matter neutron.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To say that scientists have created anti-helium-4 is a bit of an overstatement. Anti helium 4 nuclei (just the nucleus, no positrons orbiting it to make a neutral anti-atom) have been observed in LHC collisions. High energy protons collide head on and make all sorts of particles, including, very rarely, anti helium 3 and 4 nuclei. This observation is explained here: [Antinuclei production in pp collisions](https://cerncourier.com/a/antinuclei-production-in-pp-collisions/). Thus anything bigger than an antiproton is only ever produced in high energy collisions, and they are never retained for more than a few nanoseconds before they collide with the detector and annihilate on some piece of matter in the detector.

The antiproton, though, is collected at CERN, cooled in the [antiproton decelerator](https://www.home.cern/science/accelerators/antiproton-decelerator), and delivered to low-energy experiments. One of those experiments, the BASE collaboration, has checked and verified that the antiproton alone (the antihydrogen nucleus) has an infinite lifetime, as the proton does. Their paper is linked here: [Improved limit on the directly measured antiproton lifetime](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/aa7e73).

If you're willing to look beyond direct experimental evidence, I can say we do broadly expect that higher mass antiatoms will have the same radioactive decay lifetimes as their normal-atom counterparts. We aren't even close to being able to make and trap a radioactive antimatter isotope.

If you want to really know the answer to the question "do antiparticles have the same lifetime as particles" we have to look to exotic particles and their antiparticles. Unfortunately the answer becomes very complicated, and probably beyond your current level of study. In the [Kaon system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaon), we find that the particle called the Kaon and its antiparticle actually have VERY SLIGHTLY different lifetimes due to a phenomenon called [CP violation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP_violation). But this is going to be a VERY tiny effect in atoms, so the answer remains that antiatoms and normal atoms will have more or less the same lifetimes.

Comment: "Anti helium 4 nuclei (just the nucleus, no electrons orbiting it) have been observed" - Wouldn't the anti helium nucleus 'ordinarily' be orbited by positrons instead of electrons? Can electrons even orbit it?

Comment: @orlp that's of course true, OTOH positron is just the fancy name for anti-electron. So in a way, both positrons and electrons are electrons.

Comment: @orlp ha. whoops. yes you're right. I changed it. No an electron cannot orbit a negatively charged nucleus.

Comment: BTW Anderson in his original article distinguished positive and negative electrons, naming them positron and negatron, respectively. If 50% of your suggested names stick, that's already a big success. Which reminds me of the $J/\psi$ where two different groups gave it different names and the community ended up honoring both, making for a 200% success rate. Luckily, $J/\psi$ is still shorter to pronounce than electron.</end of rant>.

Comment: We’ve not verified that either the proton or antiproton have infinite lifetimes, just that they have _extremely_ long lifetimes.